# Pipenv modules not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv

I installed pipenv and then used `pipenv install beautifulsoup4`. My understanding is that this should have created a pipfile and a virtual env. So I started up `pipenv shell`. My pipfile is there, with Beautiful Soup there. Next thing I tried to do was `pipenv install selenium`. I wrote this really short script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
profile = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/user-profile-name'

driver.get(profile)

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup)
```

I tried running it and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LiScrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I tried running `python3` in the shell and just doing `import selenium` to see if it would let me check the version. Again, I got the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

What am I doing wrong with selenium that I didn't do wrong with beautiful soup??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to activate the virtual environment created by pipenv either by:

```
$ pipenv run python foo.py
```

or:

```
$ pipenv shell
> python foo.py
```

The whole process for reference:

```
$ pipenv --python 3.6.4 install beautifulsoup4 selenium
$ echo "import bs4 ; import selenium" > foo.py
$ pipenv run python foo.py
```

*Or whatever version of Python you prefer.*

(You should see no errors.)

This works for me.

Comment: It worked! Mostly... I got an error from selenium about 'geckodriver' executable needing to be in PATH, but your solution fixed my problem.

Comment: Awesome!  This should help if you haven't resolved the PATH error already.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path